# Run PHPUnit silently

Tags: content-management-system, phpunit, ezpublish

I would like to know if it is possible to run PHPUnit tests silently and to show results manualy ?

Here is my file (this is the first time I use xUNIT tests) :
https://github.com/martin-damien/sarkum/blob/b3951f6fd89b788d9abc51467a62271f32d12b8c/classes/Character.php

Am I doing it right ?

As I'm running this code inside a CMS I can't allow the tests to display something on screen out of my control...

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Whats your use case for this? Or to rephrase: Why are you doing this and are you shipping a version of phpunit with your cms then or are users expected to install phpunit for this to works or something? :)

Comment: In fact it is a personal project. I want it to be the pretiest project I ever done. So I want to use all I can to make it better. And the project is not made for redistribution but the source code will be open to be used as an exemple and a study case. (I wish to make a big tutorial at the end of the project). I don't have time constraints and I will certainly not exceed 20 users I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something :

```
ob_start();

$result = PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run( $suite );

$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And I just have to send `$buffer` to my template :)

Comment: You can combine the last two lines into `$buffer = ob_get_clean();`. See [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).